# specific settings in after/ftplugin/fortran.vim not working

Tags: vim, neovim

My `after/ftplugins/fortran.vim` has the following lines

```
let fortran_fold=1
let fortran_fold_multilinecomments=1
set foldmethod=syntax foldlevel=1 foldnestmax=2
let fortran_free_source=1
let fortran_do_enddo=1
```

If I open a fortran file, I don't see folded code, but when I change `foldmethod` to `indent` it works and I see code folded based on indentation.

The same settings work if I put them in `init.vim`.
I also have

```
syntax on
filetype indent plugin on
```

in my `init.vim`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvim enables `filetype plugin indent on` and `syntax on` by default (`:h nvim-defaults`). So, just `nvim test.for` (without any `init.vim`) would do the right thing.

But when doing it manually, the order does matter! This is correct:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

Vim suffers the same issue.